# Can intracellular protein initiate strong immune response?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, immune-system, autoimmune, immunoglobin

Some autoantibodies escape immune tolerance and can cause autoimmune disease. In order to cause harm to the tissues by these autoantibodies, do the antigen need to be extracellular or membrane bound, so that they are exposed to the immune system?

What happens if the target protein of the autoantibody is intracellular? Does the cellular localization of the target antigen plays any role?